# I always get "No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /etc/apache2/$ apache_log_dir /error.log" how cat I fix this

Tags: apache2

I am using Ubuntu Studio 12.04 and when I am trying to start apache2, I get this error message:

```
No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /etc/apache2/$ apache_log_dir /error.log
```

This meas, I should have a path like this `/etc/apache2/var/log/apache2/` but in envvars the log dir is defined as `/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX` not `/etc/apache2/`

How can I fix this.

Comment: could you please post the envvars file data through pastebin ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iHrtUMYq thats my envvars file on pastebin

Comment: What does `grep ErrorLog /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*` print?

Comment: I created the path /var/log/apache2 but every time I restart my Pc apapche2 is gone
HELP PLEASE D:

Answer (score 4):

Look at your vhosts-files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<vhost>`. In these files are defined where to find the error log for a specific website (not the global log) i.e. "default".

There are two variables to do this and per default they look like this:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Make sure that `/var/log/apache2/` exists before you start apache!