# Apache log files generation

Tags: server, apache2, logs

In my server, i found under `/var/log/apache2/`, the logs are generated as `access.log` few days ago but the are empty (for both access and error logs), this happens for all vhosts configured on my server,

And all new logs got added to `access.log.1` till this moment,
i need all new logs to be added to `access.log` and to `Error.log` files.

How to troubleshoot this issue?

`/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` as following:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 644 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
            fi
    endscript
}
```

**Editing:** I just discovered that /etc/init.d/apache2 file got empty few days ago, i don't know how!!, is there any way i can restore it?
my apache version is: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)

Comment: [Edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/618710/edit) and add the output of `cat /etc/logrotate.d/apache2`

Comment: Does the file `/var/log/access.log` exist? If so, whats the permission?

Comment: No, there is no access.log file under /var/log,
all access.log files for all vhosts on my server are under /var/log/apache2,
and they are already created 3 days ago with permissions "rw-r--r--" owner is "root:adm", 
but they are empty, as the apache still logging in access.log.1 and error.log.1

Comment: Actually, i meant `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, that was a typo....anyway check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257237/i-always-get-no-such-file-or-directory-apache2-could-not-open-error-log-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675384/how-to-enable-error-log-in-ubuntu-apache)

Comment: I just discovered now that, my /etc/init.d/apache2 file got empty 3 days ago, could it cause that issue?,
and how can i restore this file?, my apache version is: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, that could cause the issue as `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` line of `logrotate` won't be functioning then..

Comment: i have `2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4` version so the conf file might be different..rather than copy-pasting the conf file, you can reinstall `apache2` by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2` ..as there might also be some other issues, reinstalling should be a good solution..

Comment: But the reinstalling will override/remove all current configuration on apache, including current hosted sites on my server, right?

Comment: Yes, right..alternately, you can try to replace `/etc/init.d/apache2` with a version matched entry..hope that works..

Comment: Can you advise where to start searching for it, as i only can find 2.2.22 !!, aslo did you use that one before 
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2

Comment: No, i am not very sound with `apache` i am afraid..you should ask a new question about your current issue that `/etc/init.d/apache2` is missing explaining all current scenarios..if you want i can add an answer mentioning missing the conf file as the reason for logs not being generated so that this issue can be closed as solved..

Comment: Sure, i would be thankful for that, i will start new topic of the missing file,
many thanks  for your time :)

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` file you have:

```
if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
fi
```

`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}` means it will first source the file `/etc/apache2/envvars`, then if the variable `APACHE_PID_FILE` exists it will print its value which would be a file containing the PID of `apache`, if the variable does not exist it will default to value `/var/run/apache2.pid`.

The `-f` of `test` (`[`) command indicates to check for the existence of the PID, if found then run:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
```

Which will reload the configuration of `apache`.

In you case the file `/etc/init.d/apache2` is missing, hence `apache` is not reloading the configurations leading to the misbehavior of `logrotate` in saving new logs in `/var/log/apache/access.log` and `/var/log/apache/error.log`.

Comment: Many thanks my friend for your support and time.

Comment: @user225844: Happy to help :)